# QtCreator Xcode 5 file not found issue

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, clang, qt-creator

I previously had qtcreator 5.1 working with Xcode 4. I now have upgraded to Xcode 5 and I am not abble to compile my previous prject with qtcreator.

When I run, I have the following error :

```
:-1: error : /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
```

Here are the things I have tried

1. Check that Xcode was indeed installed in /Applications/Xcode
2. I have reinstalled the developper tools with Xcode 5 but it did not work.
3. I have checked in Qt creator -> preferences -> compiler -> tab compiler. I have verified that all the compiler mentionned there can be called with the terminal
4. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Qt creator (I thought this way it may have a chance to figure out where xcode had moved)

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to build an OS X or iOS project? QtCreator 2.8.1 (I guess you're referring to that) was released before XCode 5, so it might well be that XCode 5 isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installing XCode5. What you should do is to make sure XCode 5 is named as Xcode (and old Xcode deleted or renamed e.g. Xcode4) and run command

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```